# Is existential import only about implications on subject or other nouns/objects too?

Tags: predicate-logic

```
Question 1
```

[This](http://cstl-cla.semo.edu/hhill/pl120/notes/existential%20import.htm) mentions "...belief in the existence of members of the **subject** class". Is this necessarily true ?

Consider "Some pizza has pepperoni on it".

You get the following. Which is one is an existential import ?

1. Pizza exists
2. Non-pizza exists
3. pepperoni exists
4. Non-pepperoni exist
5. Cross on Sentence 1 through 4

Now,

```
 Question 2
```

[This](http://cstl-cla.semo.edu/hhill/pl120/notes/existential%20import.htm) claims existential import is rejected per *Boole*. So why are texts teaching it still ? Is it because Aristotle had it but Boole rejected it so the mention it for legacy reasons ?

Comment: See [The Traditional Square of Opposition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/square/).

Answer (score 0):

The so-called "[problem of existential import](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism#Existential_import)" arises in the context of traditional, i.e. [Aristotelian](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/) interpretation of the [Square of Opposition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/square/).

According to it,  an A proposition : "All swans are white", and an I proposition : "Some swan is white", are in a *subalternation* relation, i.e. the *subaltern* (I) must be True if the *superaltern* (A) is.

This means that the inference from A to I is - according to Aristotle - valid.

The standard translation of the [categorical proposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_proposition) A:

> "All S are P" ("all swans are white")

is: $(\forall x)(Sx → Px)$, while the corresponding I :

> "Some S is P" ("some swan is white")

is: $(\exists x) (Sx \land Px)$.

In modern terms, the conditional corresponding to A is *true* also when there are no swans at all, while the I is not.

This is the gist of

> "the truth of the proposition requires a belief in the existence of members of the subject class".

The traditional interpretation of Syllogism assumes that the class corresponding to the term in subject position is not empty.

---

There is no issue with "Some pizza has pepperoni on it"; it will be symbolized with $\exists x (Pizza(x) \land WithPep(x))$.

Obviously, the statement will be true only if there are pizzas.